# Cannot upgrade pip from 1.5.4 to latest version

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am running ubuntu gnome 14.04 and have pip 1.5.4 installed for both python 2.7.6 and python 3.4.3.

I want to upgrade pip to the latest version but when I run the command
 pip install -U pip I get the following error .

```
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/b6/ac/7015eb97dc749283ffdec1c3a88ddb8ae03b8fad0f0e611408f196358da3/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=297dbd16ef53bcef0447d245815f5144
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB): 1.3MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.4
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
  Can't roll back pip; was not uninstalled
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip'

Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpDLrBk_
```

On using sudo , i.e ;

sudo pip install -U pip

error -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pip is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
alzio@alzio-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:/$ sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: You should be using [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) when programming in python. It keeps dependencies separate and you shouldnt have any permission errors.

Comment: If you installed `pip` via the Ubuntu package (`python-pip`), you shouldn't try to upgrade it via `pip`; you should wait for Ubuntu to upgrade it, or find a newer apt-compatible source. If you want something newer than what Ubuntu is using, you should install [virtualenv](http://roundhere.net/journal/virtualenv-ubuntu-12-10/).

Comment: @Craicerjack virtualenv is not necessary. If you want to use a package system-wide, you should install it normally.

Comment: You could always uninstall `pip` in whatever way you installed it and do a fresh install using these instructions - https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: @Evert agreed but it doesnt look like he is using virtualenv, which is something he should be using

Comment: @all Actually what I want to really do is upgrade my Django from 1.6 to 1.9 but when run `pip install -U Django`  I encounter error:-                        `Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
I googled and found out this has something to do with pip version

Comment: Can you post the command that you're running?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I backed up my pip installation using

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip* .
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip local_pip
```

I then downloaded a bootstrap script and executed it:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

You can confirm that pip successfully upgraded by executing

```
pip -V
```

I got the bootstrap link from [pypa](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). I would appreciate feedback as I'm pretty sure this can be simplified, but resetting my pip version might be tricky.